# Apache broken dependency error message on recompile: Undefined symbols: "_apr_file_link

Tags: php, apache, macos, postgresql

Well, this is my first time here, and i tried to search google for an answer with this but without results.

I'm following a guide on http://russbrooks.com/2009/3/20/install-upgrade-php-apache-postgresql-on-mac-os-x-10-5-leopard to use php with postgreSQL. I got this message during the apache recompilation process:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_apr_file_link", referenced from:
      _doRotate in rotatelogs.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

...................

The guide steps i was following to get that message were:

```
cd /tmp
curl -O http://apache.mirrors.timporter.net/httpd/httpd-2.3.8.tar.gz
tar -xvzf httpd-2.3.8.tar.gz
rm httpd-2.3.8.tar.gz
cd httpd-2.3.8
./configure --enable-layout=Darwin --enable-mods-shared=all
make all
sudo make install
sudo apachectl restart
cd ..
rm -r httpd-2.3.8
```

as they're specified on the link but the make process failed.

I'm working on a MAC OS X 10.6.6 and actually i'm new at using MAC.

If anyone get this error before, some help or advice will be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

See https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49013

> httpd 2.3 requires APR 1.4, while ./configure detected your installation of
>   APR 1.3.  Upgrade APR to 1.4 and try again.

Mac OS X comes with APR 1.3.8.  If like the guide suggests you're using MacPorts to resolve dependencies, running `port install apr-util` should get the necessary version of APR, and ./configure should pick up the newer versions of the libraries automatically if /opt/local/bin is early enough in your $PATH.

Comment: This didn't work for me, fyi -- still get the undefined symbol error.